# Does checkbox in HTML input tag have any must have attributes declared?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have recently started learning Node.js and HTML. My question is when creating a new checkbox, do I have to initialize any attributes for a checkbox to successfully function or is there no such thing?

```
var newCheck = document.createElement("INPUT")
newCheck.type = "checkbox"
newDIV.appendChild(newCheck)  //newDIV is a div object
```

Would the above code run properly without any additional attributes initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just test the code?!

```js
var myBody = document.querySelector('body')
var newCheck = document.createElement("INPUT")
newCheck.type = "checkbox"
myBody.appendChild(newCheck)
```

As you can see yes it inserts a checkbox into the page, it just adds `<input type="checkbox" />`